# Conditional formatting for column of dates

Tags: function, date, google-sheets, google-docs, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a date column. I want to highlight each date that is 90 days old or older in Column "C". For single cells it's easy using `Date is before`, exact date, and then:

```
=TODAY()-90
```

but for the entire column I struggle to find how to insert the function so it keeps working for all cells. I tried something like `Date is before`, exact date, and:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TODAY()-90>C2:C200))
```

Sadly, this does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=and(today()-C1>90,C1<>"")
```

as "Custom formula is" with formatting of your choice and Range: C:C (or to suit).

[image]

The 'engine' is `today()-C1>90` but this is wrapped above in an `and` so blank cells are not also formatted by the rule.

Applies to New Google Sheets.

Comment: I don't have a "conditional formula is" in the list. I also don't have the "Range field" in your screenshot. DO I have  an old Google Docs or something? How do I update?